# Extjs form submit

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

I searched hours and hours for a solution but can't find one. I want to submit something to a php api function. it looks like this:

```
 /*global Ext:false */

Ext.onReady(function () 
{

var i = 0;
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {

         title: 'base_entity_id',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

     defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'base_entity_id',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    }],
     buttons: [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Submit',
        formBind: true,
        //only enabled once the form is valid
        disabled: true,
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
          }
    }],

    })

var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', 
{
    renderTo: 'tabs',
    id: 'tabs',
    itemId: 'tabs',
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: document.body,

    items: 
    [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            margin: 40,
            items: [form],

        },
        {
        title: 'Results',
        itemId: 'Results',
         listeners: 
            {
                activate: function (tab) 
                    {
                        if(i == 0)
                            {
                                    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', 
                                    {
                                        id: 'tabs2',
                                        width: window,
                                        height: window,
                                        renderTo: document.body,
                                    items: 
                                        [
                                            {
                                                title: '1',
                                                itemId: '1',
                                                closable: true,
                                                html: '10329u9iwsfoiahfahfosaofhasohflhsalkfhoihoi3riwoifhoiashfkhasofhosahfsahfahsfosafoisaiohfaoishfoihsaoifasoifsaifhsaoifasoihfoiahsfoihasfoihasoifoisfoihsafoihasfoiasoihasfoihaoifhaoihfoiahfoiaoaffoafoiafsaoafohaoh'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                title: '2',
                                                itemId: '2',
                                                closable: true,
                                            }
                                        ]
                                                            })
                                            tab.add(panel);
                                            tab.doLayout();
                                            i = 1;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
    }]

})
```

});

But when i'm submitting i get no response, can someone help me with this? I dont know what the next steps are...

Comment: Please, post your code for the whole form, not just the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have set no URL for your form, and the submit button doesn't have the submit method so I'm not really sure how this was supposed to work.

You will need to add the `url` config to your form:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'base_entity_id',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myBackEnd.php' // Or whatever destination you are using for your backend.
...
});
```

Also, I saw that you are using `formbind: true` and later checking if the form was valid, one action renders the other unnecessary, so choose one, there is no need for both!

Add this your button handler:

```
form.submit({
    params: {
        id: form.getForm().getValues().first
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your form was submitted successfully');
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
    }
});
```

Then you should check for `$_POST['id']`

For more information on form methods and configurations check this doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. The only problem is, how do i give my POST variabele a name? So how can i post the input value as $_POST['id'] for example?

Comment: You can add `params` to your submit method, really, check the doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit . It's all described there. I have added the `params` config to my post so you can get an example.

Comment: Ty for the quik reaction. I don't think i made myself clear enough. The value of de form has to be in the $_POST['id'] variable

Comment: Yes you did make yourself clear, I just thought giving you an example would be enough. You should send `params: {id: yourfield_value}.` I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple application done with Ext JS/PHP and the following code worked for me:

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    clientValidation: true,
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    params: {
        id: myFormPanel.getForm().getValues().first
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
               Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
       }
    }
});
```

Source:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm-method-submit